# How does the navigation through all views on apps like Facebook, Instagram and Youtube works?

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, youtube

I'm developing an Android app within a bottom bar with 4 main sections. In each section I want to be able to open new views still displaying the bottom bar. If the user goes to another main section it should be able to come back to the last section and still seeing the last view he was looking at in that section. I will it to be done like on the Instagram or Youtube app. I think it has something to do with fragments.

Comment: "I think it has something to do with fragments". Yep, checkout the [Android training guide on building dynamic UI's with them](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

Comment: You are searching for a bottom navigation bar. Refer to  [this](http://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example) tutorial to achieve the feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer by myself with this tutorial https://blog.f22labs.com/instagram-like-bottom-tab-fragment-transaction-android-389976fb8759